# Quantum scattering experiments: C-modules, N-modules and their monads

Tags: ct.category-theory, quantum-mechanics, monads

I am working on a theory of particle physics where we use monads.  I have a  few conjectures that I need to check.

1. The category of $\mathbb{C}$-modules is monadic over set
2. The category of $\mathbb{N}$-modules is monadic over Set
3. Since the monad, $\mathcal{M}_C$, which factors through the category of $\mathbb{C}$-modules is seated on Set and likewise for the monad, $\mathcal{M}_N$, that factors through the category of $\mathbb{N}$-modules, these monads compose according to functor composition.  Their composition, $\mathcal{M}_P = \mathcal{M}_C \cdot \mathcal{M}_N$, is also a monad on SET.

The physical interpretation:
The monad, $\mathcal{M}_P$, can be interpreted as complex combinations of collections of particle types.  Thus, this monad can be used to represent quantum states for the input/output of a particle scattering experiment.

Edit:

Someone has pointed out a very important fact, which is that I have to specify a distributive law for the functor composition to become a monad.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to define this.  Perhaps the question can be phrased better as follows.  Can we define a distributive law to make the composition into a monad?  What is the distributive law?  If there is a large freedom, perhaps we can select a law that captures some aspect of the physics we are trying to model.

Comment: You can’t compose monads and get another monad- you have to specify a ‘distributive’ law between them to endow the composite with the structure of a monad.

Comment: What is an N-module here?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Group carrying an N-action appropriately compatible with the group structure would obviously be the naive guess; does this not work out for some reason?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I think I mean a semimodule over the natural numbers.  That's what I mean by N-module.

Comment: Every commutative monoid is uniquely an 
$\mathbb{N}$-semimodule in the same way that an abelian group is a 
$\mathbb {Z}$-module.